# Data from mysql database do not stack when i post them in my forum

Tags: php, html, mysql

Having issues with my forum, when I try to post users posts on my forum, the posts  keep going on, on the same line, instead of stacking(paragraph) like it should. Also when there is a lot of data from my database, it simply just makes my whole website wider instead of stacking the text.

Currently I'm using php and store my data in a mysql database, the data comes from the database correctly. but again it is this problem with how the data from my database is displayed.

```
Html/php code:

<?php
require "header.php";
include 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
?>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <form action="aalesund.php" method="POST">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-25">
      <label for="subject">Subject</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-75">
      <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-25">
      <label for="content">Content</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-75">
      <textarea type="text" name="content" placeholder="Write something..." 
style="height: 200px"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-25">
      <label for="date">Date and time</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-75">
      <input type="text" name="date" placeholder="Please write the date and 
time">
    </div>
    <div class="button-container">
      <button class="postButton" type="submit" name="submit">Write 
post</button>
    </div>
    </form>

<?php
  $subject = $_POST['subject'];
  $content = $_POST['content'];
  $date = $_POST['date'];

  $sql = "INSERT INTO posts (subject, content, date) VALUES ('$subject', 
'$content', '$date');";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

  header("Location ../aalesund.php?post=succsesfull");

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC;";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

  if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      ?>
        <article class="forum">
          <h1 style="font-size: 20px"><?php echo $row['subject']; ?></h1>
          <p class="forumContent"><?php echo $row['content']; ?></p>
          <p class="forumDate"><?php echo $row['date']; ?></p>
        </article>
 <?php
    }
  }
 ?>

<?php
  require "footer.php";
 ?>

Part of the css code:

 .forumContent {
  text-align: center;
}

.forumDate {
  text-align: right;
  color: #ff9933;
}

.forum {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 5px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

(sorry for spaghetti code)

Comment: If `<p>` or `<h1>` are not blocks, do you use some CSS reset making your block elements `display: inline`?

Comment: No, im only using "text-allign: center;" for my the <p> tag and "margin/padding" for my <article> tag

Comment: Check the code in the browser source and run it through a validator to make sure everything matches up correctly. Then examine the CSS in your developer tools. It looks like you have everything closed correctly when outputting your PHP, but checking the source will verify that.

Comment: Nevertheless please check the `display` attribute of your block elements as @aynber suggested.